# How can i insert the file path and its name into a new column in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ssrs-2008, integration, etl

I'm pretty much a very beginner in SSIS, still didn't familiar with the tools, but currently working on it.
And i got an idea, how to insert the filename? because i think it'd be a great information since it'll give the information about the file path where i extract the data from.

I've already searched most of it but still didn't really get me there.

Comment: If you have (or can get) the file name into an SSIS variable you can use the derived column transformation to create a "new" column for use later in the pipeline within a Dataflow. For example, this new column would be available for an OLE DB Destination.

Comment: I've tried some of the tutorials online, using for each loop.
But here's the thing, like when i do data transferring from excel source to sql server destination, well what i wanted is that the excel file path would be also be inserted into the new columns.
at first i thought using script component, but didn't know how.
Sorry this is the first time i'm learning ssis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to build up your "ConnectionString" and/or Filename in a variable. Then you can assign the variable in a "Derived Column" Task in your "Data Flow" as a new column. That will be added to the rest of the columns that you can map to your output.

Comment: I've tried this and that but your answer is the closest solution that i've ever gotten.
Thankyou Inus C.
btw if i had like multiple files, i should use the for each or ?
because my guts telling me with foreach, but i wanted to know your opinions..

*edit* 
oh yeah and i had like some error/bugs, i had 3 columns like id,number,name.
the id value is ok, number ok, but name value when i saw it on Data Viewer it gave me <Long Text> maybe like its datatype

Comment: Yes, For each would most probably be the best. 

on the error, <Long Text> refers to the data type text in SSIS or something like varchar(max) from sql so will not display data. only if you change it to varchar(8000) and wstr,8000 will you be able to see the data in the viewer.